# Why is server not loading the models properly? (error 404)

Tags: javascript, server, model, load

For a school project I am trying to create a face recognition tool. To create this I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVClHLwv-4I).

The code runs fine in Visual Studio code with live server (running live server is a key but I can't figure out why this is so important)

But now I'm trying to put my work on a real server (server is granted to us by school). But when I upload all the files to my school server the console says it couldn't find the right models. The link the console tries to fetch the files from seems right so I'm confused and can't figure out what the problem is.

Code that loads the models:

```
Promise.all([
faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('./models'),
faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('./models'),
faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('./models'),
faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('./models'),
]).then(startVideo)
```

Server build-up:

[image: Picture about how the server structure looks like]

Console error log:

[image: Picture of the console with the fetch errors]

Comment: maybe this is javascript, not java?

Comment: True, sorry my fault in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have another check that the file path you have provided is correct. For example, it may work locally with just `('./models')`. But check if the school server requires you to provide the root file path. Let me know if this works.

Comment: It seems like the paths are correct. If i would copy the path from filezilla to download the file i'm getting this link (ftp://swalrave@student.aii.avans.nl/CMD/swalrave/models/face_landmark_68_tiny_model-shard1). If i delete the ftp://swalrave@student.aii.avans.nl part the file doesn't work anymore.

Comment: perhaps `CMD/swalrave/models/`?

Comment: No in that case it is retrieving from CMD/swalrave/CMD/swalrave which isn't a path at all. The root folder where all the files are located is CMD/swalrave.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a generic approach to this issue, for didacting reasons.

You can to use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from Microsoft SysUtils. It can monitor any application for file system activity like reading directories or files. I recommend to use it to check where your application is actually reading from and where those paths are pointing to.

Comment: And do i need to monitor Chrome as a proces or how do i monitor this properly?

Comment: you monitor the process that looks for the files. if your server runs locally, you monitor its process. if it runs remotely, procmon has to run remotly. procmon is also windows only, I forgot to metion that.

Comment: for the record: this answer became irrelevant after OP corrected the tags of the question